# Combining 2 queries into one if one of the value is not 0

Tags: sql-server

I have the below queries and I want to get @BillCardName:

```
DECLARE     
  @BillSet        int,
  @BillCardName   varchar(50)

-- get @BillCardName from a table 1st
SELECT @BillSet = BillSet,
    @BillCardName = vInvBriefDesc
FROM BillTableA
    WHERE ID = 1234

--If we have a iBillingSetID, we need the description from another table
IF @BillSet <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @BillCardName = vBillDescription
        FROM BillTableB
    WHERE BillSet = @BillSet
END
```

I am able to write the above and wondering if the above can be combined into one query?

Comment: Even though your question got answered,you may want to check this to improve question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT join both table and use CASE WHEN to check for BillSet <> 0

```
SELECT BillCardName = CASE WHEN  a.BillSet <> 0
                           THEN  b.vBillDescription 
                           ELSE  a.vInvBriefDesc 
                           END
FROM   BillTableA a
       LEFT JOIN BillTableB b ON a.BillSet = b.BillSet
WHERE  a.ID = 1234
```

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel, I am trying to use CASE too but do not know to combine with LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're aiming for here can be accomplished using a left (outer) join and `coalesce` (which returns the first non-null value in a given sequence).

```
DECLARE     
  @BillSet        int,
  @BillCardName   varchar(50)

SELECT @BillSet = bta.BillSet,
    @BillCardName = coalesce (btb.vBillDescription, bta.vInvBriefDesc)
FROM BillTableA as bta
LEFT JOIN BillTableB as btb
    ON bta.BillSet = btb.BillSet
    --uncomment the line below if 0 is a valid value for BillSet in BillTableB
    --AND bta.BillSet <> 0
    WHERE bta.ID = 1234
END
```